# CSV file does not exist

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pull the file "house_date.csv" and I ma being unssucesful becasue python is stating that the file cannot be found. is there a better way for me to figure out how  I can load the file ? I am also not sure in what directory is located.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import math 




pd.read_csv('house_data.csv')
```

This is the error message I am getting .
[image]

Comment: You need to figure out the directory before asking this question

Answer (score 0):

When you write `pd.read_csv('house_data.csv')`, the csv file directory and the python working directory is supposed to be the same.
Try to replace *house_data.csv* with the complete path (for example `C:/house_data.csv`, if the file is in *"C"*).

Comment: Thtat's not correct. The file is expected in the working directory which might be or not be the same as the directory where the Python file is. If you want to make sure to take the file from the same directory then `import pathlib` and do `filename = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'house_data.csv'`.